# Graph traversal using py2neo

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I want to retrieve all the relationships and nodes present between two nodes from the graph I created using neo4j. I am using `py2neo` and I want to know how can we write a `cypher` query which can retrieve intermediate relationships between two nodes and also the intermediate nodes between those two nodes.

For ex:

```
(A)-[relation1]->(B)-[relation2]->(C)-[relation3]->(D)
```

If I give `A` as starting node and `D` as ending node, I want the output to be as set of relations `relation1,relation2,relation3` and set of intermediate nodes as `B` and `C`.

Comment: Do you mean something like [`nodes()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-nodes) and `relationships()`?

Answer (score 0):

match mypath=(A)-[:*0..]->(D) return nodes(mypath), relationships(mypath)